# Jasmine: can't test function being passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

This is my js file:

```
My.File = {
    someMethod: function() {
        var finalURL = "https://some.url.com"
        var somePostCall = $.post(My.URL, {
            sessionToken: My.Session.sessionToken
        });
        somePostCall.done(function(response) {
            //do something with the response   ===> I want to test this function, and mock the 'response'

        });
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to write a test which covers the function being passed in the "done" call. I don't want to make the actual ajax call, I want to moke the response from the http call, and still want to have the somePostCall promise to being invoked. And when the "done" method, the 'response' has to be mocked with something made up by me.

I've been trying to capture the response from the $.post call. Like this:

```
spyOn($, 'post').and.callThrough();
My.File.someMethod();
var promise = $.post.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
```

The problem is that .args[0] doesn't return the value from $.post, it is just the params being passed. If I can spy the response from $.post, then I can spy it, and capture the function being passed to the 'done' method. So that way I can at least call it manually, and pass a mocked 'response'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`.args[0]` Doesn't return resolved promise. It' just checks the parameters passed to the function. And it's also async. So your expectation need to await until promise is resolved.

```
My.File = {
    someMethod: function() {
        var finalURL = "https://some.url.com"
        return $.post(finalURL, { // return the promise
            sessionToken: My.Session.sessionToken
        });
    }
}
```

spec file.

```
it('some spec', async () => { // Async
  spyOn($, 'post').and.callThrough();
  const response = await My.File.someMethod();

  // check if post method is called with correct arguments e.g My.URL is what you expect
  const url = $.post.calls.mostRecent().args[0]
  expect(url).to.be("https://some.url.com");

  // test the response 
});
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay. Unfortunately, I can't share the exact code, because it belongs to an organization, and I'm not allowed to share it. I posted a similar version of it, and well, your answer doesn't fix my issue. Basically, the only way to get a pointer to an anonymous function, is to execute the real logic, and then get the param (which is the pointer to the anonymous function). Then, I can manually execute the pointer, and pass to it whatever parameter I want.

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation about pointers and anonymous function. In the spec file you provided you're calling the promise. you're not waiting until it's resolved before testing. So you need to wait until promise is resolved.

Comment: Right, but the anonymous function has code inside of it. Has logic. Branches, conditions, etc. All driven by the 'response' from the promise. How can I mock the 'response'?

Comment: if you want to mock then you need to refer to testing frame work documentations. if you're using it would be something like `spyOn($, 'post').and.returnValue(mockResponse);`